# How do I test a Cloudfront Distribution with the same CNAME as an existing Distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, networking, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

Our team uses Cloudfront to act as a cache + dynamic reverse proxy so that:

> example.com/foo

is directed to our Foo elasticbeanstalk environment and

> example.com/bar

is directed to our Bar elasticbeanstalk environment.

Now, we have been working on a pretty hefty rearchitecting of some of our `example.com` services, and now we will want `example.com/foo` to go to our Foo2 environment, and some other things such as `example.com/baz` to Baz, and so on (while keeping some existing rules such as `/bar` to Bar).

We would like not to just "flip the switch" and do it in production, and would like to test our configuration beforehand. So we set up another distribution with the new behaviors and put benign sample applications for `Foo2` and `Baz`.  But of course - we cannot set the `example.com` CNAME on this other distribution, because our CURRENT distribution already uses it.

When we tried to "verify" by editing our `/etc/hosts` file to point `example.com` to one of the IP addresses from one of the A records from our *new* distribution, Cloudfront appeared to just behind the scenes see that we were trying to request the host `example.com` and routed requests to the environments specified by the behaviors in our *current* distribution.

**Is there any way we can test and verify Cloudfront ruleset changes to a distribution with an existing CNAME without changing the behaviors and rules applied to the current distribution?**

Comment: You can, of course, use a second distribution, but you can't access it with the hostname of another distribution in your browser's `Host` request header.  You can test using the assigned CloudFront hostname, e.g. `dxxxexample.cloudfront.net` or by associating a new hostname, e.g. `preview.example.com` with the new (test) distribution.  The fact that you didn't do this leads me to ask: why not?  What is it about your setup that prevents this approach from being usable?  Do you have hard-coded absolute URLs? Does your origin need to see `example.com` in the forwarded `Host` header? Or...?

Answer (score 1):

> We would like not to just "flip the switch" and do it in production,
>   and would like to test our configuration beforehand.

When using services like CloudFront for multiple stages such as testing, staging & production to test the configuration, the recommended way is to first make the infrastructure configurations to code using AWS CloudFormation.

When you keep infrastructure modifications in code with versioning(Similar to source code), you can apply the change to one environment and test, and if everything works fine, you you can push the same change other environments.

> Is there any way we can test and verify Cloudfront ruleset changes to
>   a distribution with an existing CNAME without changing the behaviors
>   and rules applied to the current distribution?

This is not possible. When you do configuration changes to the distribution, the rules will be applied, modifying its behaviors. Therefore as stated above, this will require more than one distribution for each environment to test the configuration.

In addition, unless your application code uses the domain headers ( e.g Host, Origin) in the program (e.g example.com), you can test the application with the AWS assigned domain name to CloudFront (e.g xxxxxx.cloudfront.net)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign multiple CNAME's to a single distribution. All CNAME's must be comma separated. You can test only HTTP connections and not HTTPS. You can apply only one custom domain certificate for a given distribution.

You can have upto 100 CNAME's for a single distribution. Check the limits in the following link. If you want more you can request via support request.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_cloudfront

This will help to test without changing anything in your origins or behaviors.

Hope it helps.